# Postfix: how to block incoming emails to a specific recipient?

Tags: postfix-mta

I have Postfix set up to deliver all incoming email to ⟨any_random_address⟩@mydomain.com to myname@mydomain.com. I've recently noticed that a large percentage of spam is going to the same non-existent username, and I'd like to block incoming email to that username, while still sending all other emails to my inbox. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that catch-all doesn't really make sense:

In your virtual aliases map (e.g. `/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps`), add the following line:

```
john.doe@example.com devnull
```

In /etc/aliases, add the following line:

```
devnull:  /dev/null
```

This defines a mailbox named `devnull` and stores its contents in `/dev/null`.

Don't forget to update the alias caches and restart Postfix, for example like

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps
sudo newaliases
sudo service postfix restart
```

Now you should be fine.

Comment: I'm using virtual aliases with regexp so devnull: /dev/null ends tup  to=</dev/null@tp23.org> then is not discarded its bounced.
any idea how to do this with some other trick?